# Get country from timezone

Tags: country

i have a news script

and it multi language ..

i want detect automaticlly the language of the visitor ...

i found more questions here about get the country from javascript timezone

them problem was because more citis is Similar time

" I DONT WANT DETECT COUNTRY " <- if that hard to get it !

only language !

so , what is the best way to get the visitor language or country by javascript ?

i don't understand javascript ever ! , and can't know what you can do by javascript

my two ideas is ..

first idea

get the time of visitor

example

EG = 0300

and in php i make an array contain ('0200'=>'Egypt') and another array ('Egypt'=>'AR')

second idea

in my clock time zone box , i see

Time Zone : Cairo <- egypt

can we get the name ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 3):

You do not want to use time zones to determine language. People in the same time zone can speak different languages.

One alternative is to check the [accept-language](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.4) header.

For a similar discussion see: [How do you detect a website visitor's country (Specifically, US or not)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156231/how-do-you-detect-a-website-visitors-country-specifically-us-or-not)

Comment: i don't understand this information based on what ! , but i tried it from 3 computers for my friends ! , result is en-us,en;q=0.5 and they can't speak english !

Comment: @Osama are they running an English browser/operating system/environment? accept-language is usually set by the browser.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get the country or language from the time zone offset.

For example, take UTC+1 in winter time. This could be France, Spain, Norway, Germany, Belgium, etc. They're all in Central European Time.

If you can get an Olsen name such as "Europe/France" or "Europe/Germany" that clearly gives you a lot more information, but you can't get that just from the offset from UTC.

Answer (score 0):

Generally this can work, kinda.

But you would not get an specific location.

Especially in Europe and Africa there can be a lot of countries in one time zone and you couldnt differ between them.

I hope this helps

anmother way to do it
ip location: http://www.geobytes.com/iplocator.htm?getlocation

http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/04/get-geographical-location-geolocation.html

from the ip you can find teh country and language would work for most countries except for canada etc...

Comment: Sadly news ,, so is there any other way to get language ?