# How can I get analytics for a single .txt file on a XAMPP server?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, xampp

I have an EC2 instance running a XAMPP server. I have a file inside htdocs that I want analytics for

The directory structure is simple `htdocs\a\b.txt`

I just need basic analytics like how many times it's been accessed per week and from which countries

I'm not sure if AWS CloudWatch would give me analytics for this file but I don't want to use it since it's not free. what's an easy/quick way to get analytics for this file?

Comment: Analytics is a very broad term. What information do you actually want?

Comment: So there will be multiple files to parse?
What exactly You want to get from this file(s)? Search each line for a string ocurence?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to pay for any such analytics service, then you could write your own code.

Assuming you just want the number & country of visitors, you could use the [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156231/how-do-you-detect-a-website-visitors-country-specifically-us-or-not) code for country data & something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18799808/how-do-i-count-unique-visitors-to-my-site) for visitor count.

You could modify the codes in the link & save the relevant data (country, timestamp etc.) to a file or database.